# how to reset ball after 10 second of wait

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make ball reset 10 second delay after ball thrown 
ball is resting properly. But how to delay ball reset please help me out.
ball reset is too quick.
I have used the function also but its not working properly please help me 
i am at the end of the game stage.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {
public Vector3 launchVeclocity;
//private const float RESET_TIME = 5.0f; // time to be taken for reset 
public bool inPlay = false;

private Vector3 ballStartPos;
private Rigidbody rigidBody;
private AudioSource audioSource;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    //rigidBody.useGravity = false;
    ballStartPos = transform.position;
}

public void Launch (Vector3 velocity)
{
    inPlay = true;

    rigidBody.useGravity = true;
    rigidBody.velocity = velocity;

    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    audioSource.Play ();
}
void Update() {
    Waiting ();

}
public void Reset() {

    inPlay = false;
    //yield return new WaitForSeconds (5);


    transform.position = ballStartPos;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    rigidBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    rigidBody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    rigidBody.useGravity = false;

}

    IEnumerator Waiting ()
{
    Reset ();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);
}




 }
```

Comment: haven't used unity myself but http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/350721/c-yield-waitforseconds.html may help

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be firing that coroutine on every frame as you are currently by calling it within Update() (but that's not the question you asked).  The reason why it's not actually waiting though is because you are calling Waiting() directly instead of using StartCoroutine(Waiting()).

Comment: Well... you are also calling 'Reset()' before your WaitForSeconds(10) so it wouldn't work in it's current form because of that either.  There's just a lot that needs work up there man.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume `Launch` is the method that throws the ball.

Firstly, remove the call to `Waiting()` from your `Update` method, you don't want call the `Waiting()` method directly like that.
You need to start a [Coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) in your Launch method:

```
public void Launch (Vector3 velocity)
{
    inPlay = true;

    rigidBody.useGravity = true;
    rigidBody.velocity = velocity;

    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    audioSource.Play ();

    // start the Coroutine to introduce the reset delay
    StartCoroutine(Waiting()); 
}

IEnumerator Waiting ()
{
    // suspect executing in this routine for 10 seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);
    // now call reset
    Reset();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Well the function is working but still ball is resting as before can I inactive the ball for some second

Answer (score 0):

Use [Invoke()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html), it's way easier.
You've already got the method so it would just require this as your Launch() method:

```
public void Launch (Vector3 velocity)
{
    inPlay = true;

    rigidBody.useGravity = true;
    rigidBody.velocity = velocity;

    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    audioSource.Play ();
    Invoke("Reset", 10);
}
```

You can get rid of the whole `Waiting()` method

Answer (score 0):

[Systeam.Threading.Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
IEnumerator Waiting ()
{
    Reset ();
    yield return Thread.Sleep(10000); // In miliseconds.
}
```